# Can we picture metallic bonding as an equilibrium between electrons and cations?

Tags: bond, ions, metal

Can we picture metallic bonding as an equilibrium between electrons and cations?

Suppose:

> $$\ce{Al^3+ + 3e- <=> Al}$$

Comment: I mean isn't $\ce{Al^3+}$ stable, why would it need the extra electrons since its outer shell is stable?

Comment: Related although not a direct duplicate. http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/25003/clarification-for-metallic-bond?rq=1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In metals, electrons are non-localized, forming a "sea" of electrons, rather than having them localized, as in the $\ce{Na+Cl-}$ lattice of crystalline salt. See [Metallic bonding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metallic_bonding) for a more complete description.

It is, of course, a matter of degree, as covalent, ionic and metallic bonding can "blend" from one to the other. A bond can be considered *partially* ionic and covalent, for example; see these [helpful graphics](http://www.longview.k12.wa.us/ralong/tietjen/Chemistry/Metallic.JAT.pdf)